# How do we change the indexes of a list without changing the original list on python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, python-requests

I'm trying to add 2 to the elements of a list without
changing the elements of the original list in python. I used the append method, but when I try to return the original is modified too.
It should work like this:

```
>> list1 = [1, 3, 5]
>> add_two(list1)
[3, 5, 7]
>> list1 == [1, 3, 5]
True
```

However this is what I got:

```
>> list1 = [1, 3, 5]
>> add_two(list1)
[3, 5, 7]
>> list1
[3, 5, 7]
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Add `add_two` method in question!

Comment: Do read [mcve] for formatting help.

Comment: @ParthS007 It seems like `add_two` is adding `2` to each element in the list. But then I don't get why he expects  `list1 == [1, 3, 5]` to still be `true`.

Comment: Because it should add 2 in a new list

Answer (score 0):

List is a mutable data type. If you want to manipulate it without changing the original, you should pass the copy of that list to the function add_two().

```
In [1]: def add_two(lst):
   ...:     lst[2] += 2
   ...:     return lst
   ...:

In [2]: a = [ 1,2,3]

In [3]: add_two(a)
Out[3]: [1, 2, 5]

In [4]: a
Out[4]: [1, 2, 5]

In [5]: add_two(a.copy())
Out[5]: [1, 2, 7]

In [6]: a
Out[6]: [1, 2, 5]
```

**EDIT**

I see you want to increase each list element by two.
Then it is easiest to use list comprehension - creates a new list, no need to pass a copy...

```
def add_two(lst):
     return [v+2 for v in lst]
```

Comment: It would be best to make the list copy within the function, as it's part of its workings and the user shouldn't be bothered about it. As for the specific example of adding 2 to each element, `return [element + 2 for element in lst]` will suffice.

Comment: Yes, right. Here I wanted also to show the original behavior. For final usage making a copy inside of a function would be better.